# JS code guessing game color NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am a neophyte JS, I'm making a game where the user has to guess a randomly generated color.

I noticed that the code I tried to write results in errors, that is, when I go to enter a color in the prompt, even if it is wrong always says the right thing. I have something wrong in check_guess function where I wrote the conditions.

Another mistake I detected when the game ends, should be out in the background the color that guessed it, nor should you.

Can you help me figure out where I'm wrong?

```js
while (!finished) {
            guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" +
              colors_message + "\n\n What is the color am I thinking of?");
            guess_input = guess_input_text.toLowerCase();
            guesses += 1;
            finished = check_guess();
          }
        }

        function check_guess() {
          if (guess_input == -1) {
            alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color. \n\n Please try again.");
            return false;
          } else if (guess_input > target) {
            alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: Your color is alphabetically higher than mine.\n\nPlease try again.");
            return false;
          } else if (guess_input < target) {
            alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: Your color is alphabetically lower than mine.\n\nPlease try again.");
            return false;
          } else {
            alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game!\n\nYou can see the colour in the background.");
            var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            myBody.style.background = target;

            return true;
          }
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: We can't debug the whole program for you. Have to pick one problem and edit your question or repost focusing on that problem only per stackoverflow rules.  If you don't fix they may close the question.

Comment: @AuroraRuggieri You'll need to provide us with more data in your post, like what are `colors_message`, `guesses`, `target`, `finished`, etc?

Comment: @AuroraRuggieri i got the data i was asking from you, and have got an answer for this Q below. accept it if you find it correct and close this Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to your code revisions I got the required data. There were few glitches that were found like:

1. You were checking `guess_input` with `target`, where `guess_input` holds a string value of the user input and `target` holds an integer value of the correct answer. None of the conditions will ever be satisfied in this case, and thus the last `else` part will be executed always. That is, `alert("Congratulations! You ha..);`
2. `myBody.style.background = target;` will set the `background`
   property to an integer (index of answer in `colors` array). You need
   to set it like `myBody.style.background = colors[target];`

Below is the working code:

```js
var colors = ["antiquewhite", "blueviolet", "crimson", "deepskyblue", "forestgreen", "gold", "lawngreen", "magenta", "palegreen", "skyblue"];
var colors_message = colors.join(", ");
var target;
var guess_input_text;
var guess_input;
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;
var ask_again = false;


function do_game() {
 var target_index = Math.random() * colors.length;
 var target_index_integer = Math.floor(target_index);
 target = target_index_integer;

 var answer = String(colors[target]).toLowerCase();
 //Alert correct answer for testing purposes
 alert("The correct answer is: " + answer);


    guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + colors_message + "\n\n What is the color am I thinking of?");
    while (!finished) {
        if(ask_again){
           guess_input_text = prompt("What is the color I was thinking of?");
           }
            guess_input = guess_input_text.toLowerCase();
            guesses += 1;
            finished = check_guess(colors.indexOf(guess_input));
        }
    }

    function check_guess(guess_index) {
        ask_again = true;
        if (guess_index == -1) {
            alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color. \n\n Please try again.");
            return false;
        } else if (guess_index > target) {
            alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: Your color is alphabetically higher than mine.\n\nPlease try again.");
            return false;
        } else if (guess_index < target) {
            alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: Your color is alphabetically lower than mine.\n\nPlease try again.");
            return false;
        } else {
           ask_again = true;
            alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game!\n\nYou can see the colour in the background.");
            var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            myBody.style.background = colors[target];
            return true;
        }
     }
```

```html
<body onload="do_game()"></body>
```

Comment: I thank you for the clarification, it was helpful to understand where I went wrong and to grow, thanks again.

Comment: @AuroraRuggieri You can close this question now if your problem is solved